# How to display forms for some users Odoo 10

Tags: python, odoo

I work with Odoo 10.

In Front-End Development, I have different forms available today for all types of users. I would like to post only certain forms. In backend development, I create a boolean type field that will allow me to tell if this form will be visible to a public or authenticated user. The problem is that I do not know how to create a Python function to differentiate the two types of users with this boolean. Do I have to use the controller? Or rather do a function in my corresponding class? Here are the codes:

class :

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from odoo import models, fields, api, http, exceptions


class InheritedWebsiteApplicationTemplate(models.Model):

    # region Private attributes
    _inherit = 'website.application.template'
    # endregion

    # region Fields declaration
    user_not_connected = fields.Boolean(string="Formulaire pour utilisateur non connecté")
```

controller :

```
@http.route(['/my/web-demarche'], type='http', auth="public", method=['GET'], website=True)
# @http.route(['/my/web-demarche'], type='http', auth='user', method=['GET'], website=True)
def get_demarche(self, date_begin=None, date_end=None, **post):
    """Display all requests owned by the current user."""
    template_name = 'grc.demarche'
    context = self._prepare_portal_layout_values()

    # On va chercher les demandes de l'utilisateur, le filtre se fait par un ir.rule
    domain = []
    archive_groups = self._get_archive_groups('website.application', domain)
    if date_begin and date_end:
        domain += [('create_date', '>=', date_begin), ('create_date', '<', date_end)]

    domain += [('applicant_id', '=', request.env.uid)]
    user_requests = request.env['website.application'].sudo().search(domain)

    # On va chercher les modèles de demandes actifs (mais pas ceux sans demande multiple si déjà demandés)
    request_templates = get_available_requests(request.env.user, user_requests)

    if request.httprequest.method == 'POST':
        if post.get('suivi', False):
            record_ticket = request.env['website.application'].search([('name','=',str(post.get('suivi', False)))], limit=1)
            if record_ticket:
                return request.redirect('/my/web-demarche/' + str(record_ticket.name))
            else:
                context.update({'error_not_found': True})

    context.update({
        'website_requests': user_requests,
        'request_templates': request_templates,
        'archive_groups': archive_groups,
        'date': date_begin
    })

    return request.render(template_name, context)
```

Result (template) :

[image]

Comment: You should create one "simple" form view with everything in it for every user. Then create two or more extension views with everything for one special user group. The view model `ir.ui.view` has a field which uses Odoo's access groups to either "render" or not. Just fill it with the groups needed.

Comment: Here an example from [Odoo sale app](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/6e71cf8a71d0713945947a4e96a9b70978d7f90d/addons/sale/views/sale_views.xml#L366-L378). Usually the sales order lines are inline editable. But if a user is in special access groups (packaging, mrp properties) he will get a popup on the lines.

Comment: I do not see why I will use pure XML in this context because I work with QWeb. So it's with templates. (t -if: t-foreach ...)
I do not understand these answers. Thanks anyway.
cordially

Comment: QWeb templates generate records for model `ir.ui.view`, too. They are type=qweb. Just go to technical in the view list and filter for qweb.

Comment: For example on my image, you see "Demande d'inscription scolaire" and "Demande d'inscription scolaire hors ligne".
I want the "Demande d'inscription scolaire hors ligne" not visible when connected. I display the different forms through a t-foreach. Do you think that's the solution? If I filter my forms it will be for everyone knowing that I use a loop, do not you think? cordially